# Lookup S3 Bucket and add a trigger to invoke a lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm using the new AWS CDK(Cloud Development Toolkit) to build the infrastructure on AWS in Java.

**What I have to do:** lookup an s3 bucket and add a trigger that invokes a lambda function.

**What I have done:**

- Looked up s3 bucket:

  ```
  IBucket bucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(scope, bucketId, bucketName);
  ```
- Add a new event source to the existing lambda:

  ```
  IEventSource eventSource = getObjectCreationEvent();
  lambda.addEventSource(eventSource);
  ```
- Where `getObjectCreationEvent()` is:

  ```
  private S3EventSource getObjectCreationEvent() {
      return new S3EventSource(bucket, new S3EventSourceProps() {
          @Override
          public List<EventType> getEvents() {
              return Collections.singletonList(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

**What is the problem:**

The type of `bucket` parameter in the `S3EventSource` constructor is `Bucket` but every lookup method (e.g. the `Bucket.fromBucketName()`) returns an `IBucket` and not a `Bucket`, so there is a signature mismatch. If I cast `IBucket` to `Bucket` I have a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Do you have to use the CDK?

Comment: You could get the bucket from the Stack.

Comment: Not the solution you are looking for, but as a work around you could have the s3Bucket+Trigger created as an infrastructure project. Make sure that you have your lambda created beforehand, though.

Answer (score 3):

From the git issue tracker https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2004#issuecomment-479923251

> Due to current limitations with CloudFormation and the way we implemented bucket notifications in the CDK, it is impossible to add bucket notifications on an imported bucket. This is why the event source uses s3.Bucket instead of s3.IBucket.
>
> You could use onPutObject:

```
const bucket = s3.Bucket.import(this, 'B', {
  bucketName: 'my-bucket'
});

const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'F', {
  code: lambda.Code.inline('boom'),
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NodeJS810,
  handler: 'index.handler'
});

bucket.onPutObject('put-object', fn);
```

But reading further on, this doesn't seem to work anymore either.

It seems the answer currently is:

It's impossible to set up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be possible to set it up like this now:

```
const lambdaDestination = new s3n.LambdaDestination(fn);
bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, lambdaDestination);
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/15158