# AWS CDK - add an s3 trigger to invoke a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm trying to build a lambda function with s3 trigger throw the CDK deployment, does somebody knows if it possible to programmatically trigger the CDK code?

I found those links:

1. [Lookup S3 Bucket and add a trigger to invoke a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282173/lookup-s3-bucket-and-add-a-trigger-to-invoke-a-lambda)
2. [With CDK, can it be triggered through a lambda to deploy the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888249/with-cdk-can-it-be-triggered-through-a-lambda-to-deploy-the-stack)

but they were a few months ago and I wanted to know if anything was renewed

Comment: seems weird to me to use lambda for this. you could use codebuild and simply run cdk deploy in it. You can trigger CodeBuild via the SDK and maybe have a lambda that triggers codebuild that deploys cdk? :D

what are you trying to do if I may ask.

Comment: I'm trying to build a lambda function that resizes images, the cdk deploy is run fine, I only need the part with triggers for s3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to trigger a lambda after a file was uploaded to S3 you have two ways:

**S3 Eventnotifications:**

this is a S3 specific feature and supports lambda as a target and also SQS and SNS. You can find more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

**CloudTrail:**

CloudTrail logs pretty much all Events in your account and you can react to them if you want.

1. create a bucket
2. Create a trail, you might want to select write only, to reduce the amount of stuff that gets written
3. add the bucket to the trail with addS3EventSelector
4. add your target

```js
        uploadBucket.onCloudTrailWriteObject('cwEvent', {
            target: new targets.LambdaFunction()
        })
```

this will create a CloudWatch Event.

On the first step you might need to also log it to cloud watch logs, I'm not sure anymore:

```js
        const trail = new cloudtrail.Trail(this, 'CloudTrail', {
            sendToCloudWatchLogs: true,
            managementEvents: cloudtrail.ReadWriteType.WRITE_ONLY,
        });
```

I prefer version two, because CloudWatch Event supports way more targets than SQS, SNS and Lambda. I used it to trigger a Step Function for example.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudtrail-readme.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#bucket-notifications